# Accordion and jQueryCycle prevent href's from working

Tags: java, html, accordion, jquery-cycle

Checkout [this site](http://sensenich.bythepixel.com/) that I'm working on.

The idea is as follows:

-That the slide show is supposed to rotate - this works

-When hovering over the menu on the right the appropriate slide appears - this works

-Also when hovering the nav should expand to show a brief description - this works

-When clicking on Airboat, Aircraft, UAV, or the "view" link it then takes you to that page - this doesn't work.  I'm sure what's happening here is that the javascripts are fighting it out, as disabling one makes the links work, reenabling breaks it.

Your help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
 return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') > a';}
```

instead of

```
return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';}
```

in your cycle plugin.  Using the direct descendent selector instead of the descendent selector will keep it from matching on the links contained in the accordion for the page anchors.

Comment: thanks for the tip, this actually fixed the links in the accordion content, but not the actual anchor link.  

ie, the 'view' links work, but the Airboat, Aircraft, UAV anchor links do not.  btw, i made the change so you can see the result.

Comment: Actually if I place the href inside the h3 it fixes the issue.  Although I'm sure I'm breaking like a thousands rules by doing that.

Comment: Why not just add a click handler to the header that uses the "view" link's href when clicked?

Comment: thanks... that put me in the right direction... i actually made the entire ul clickable.. which is even better